# How to retrieve the account info of an account that sits on a different node?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am dealing with corda accounts. I have two nodes. Seller and Receiver. Both nodes have some accounts, say sellerA, sellerB, receiverA, and receiverB. I want to send an NFT from sellerA to receiverA. But I'm unable to access the receiverA account info from Seller node. How can I do that?

This is what I tried.

```
AccountInfo receiverAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this)
            .accountInfo(buyer).get(0).getState().getData();
```

But it returned,

```
Event: Error(exception=java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Empty list doesn't contain element at index 0.)
```

Comment: Did you share the accounts between the node after you created them?

Comment: Yes, I have shared.

Comment: Can you share how you shared the accounts? That should work.

Comment: start ShareAccountInfoFlow accountName: receiverA, shareAccountInfoTo: Seller

Comment: Did you try to not use the UtilitiesKt (which I think does not exist anymore)? Link to a java example: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/a5f89700ac602e356fc5f39a760e1c5dfc52f2ee/Accounts/supplychain/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/supplychain/flows/SendInvoice.java#L49

Answer (score 1):

The error means your Account query in your node is returning an empty list. It is probably caused by passing in an invalid parameter. The buyer variable needs to be a string and needs to be Case-Sensitive.

As Alessandro said in the comment, the account sharing is done from the counterparty node. You would not need to do anything from the receiving node.

As for the UtilitiesKt, you can still use it. We were just trying to not use any kotlin class in our latest java samples.